# Mongo DB Cluster Replica set

Tags: mongodb, cluster-computing

is it possible to make primary member of replica set a secondary member of another replica set in MongoDB?

Comment: no, it's not possible.  each node can only be a member of one replica set.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky Convert your response to an answer so it can be acceped and seen by others with the same question ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible to make a primary of one replica set be a secondary in another replica set with MongoDB itself. Each node can only be a member of one replica set and that's specified when you start it up.

What you could do instead is implement your own version of replication - reading the oplog.rs collection in the local database of that other cluster to get data into this replica set's primary.

Luckily there is an implementation of that in [this project](https://github.com/10gen-labs/mongo-connector).  This is a [blog post that describes the basic functionality](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/29127828146/introducing-mongo-connector) and of course since it's open source you can adjust it for your needs or translate the implementation to your language of choice, etc.